# game is lagging cause of extra objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, lag, frame-rate

I'm making a 2d game in unity3d. I'm trying to minimize all lags, I'm very careful with all colliders and other stuff, I move colliders only with rigidbody methods. And profiler shows around 60 fps.

BUT, now it's time to add enemies (about 50 identical gameObjects with boxcollider and rigidbody). And game starts lagging after I add all 50 enemies in inspector ( 15fps ). Profiler shows huge rise of overhead. What can in be? Thank you.

Comment: without seeing any code we can't help (ie equals shooting in the dark or whatever the saying is)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Object Pooling](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling) to solve this problem.

> You may have made games in the past that created and destroyed a lot
>   of items (such as bullets or enemies). What you may not have known is
>   that the act of instantiating and destroying are inefficient and can
>   slow your projects down.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but I've just figured out my mistake. I know, that instantiating is a long process, but I wanted to make instantiations in a preloader screen. My mistake is in enemy's script. It overloads the system.